# Angularjs-Charts - Como mostrar valores monetários no gráfico

Tags: angularjs

Eu estou usando a biblioteca `angular-charts.js`

quero mostrar os valores que retornam do banco, formatados em valores monetários

```
$scope.series = ['Valor Etapa', 'Valor Realizado', 'Resultado'];
$scope.labels = [];
$scope.data = [];
if (typeof json== 'object') {

              $scope.labels = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return item.etapa_projeto
            })

            $scope.data.push($.map(data, function(item) {
                return item.valor_etapa
            }))
            $scope.data.push($.map(data, function(item) {
                return item.valor_realizado
            }))
            $scope.data.push($.map(data, function(item) {
                return item.resultado
            }))
          }
```

### data

```
   data[
        0:{
            etapa_projeto:"modulo controle"
             resultado:"500.00"
             situacao:"Em Andamento"
             valor_etapa:"1000.00"
             valor_realizado:"500.00"
           }  
         ]
```

### gráfico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a directiva filter diretamente no seu controller dessa forma

```
    $filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)

    $scope.data.push($.map(data, function(item) 
    {
         return  $filter('currency')(item.valor_realizado, 'R$',2); 
    }))
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter